# Is it possible to make a shader extend another shader in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

I want to make a couple of GPU textures using perlin noise and whatnot, so I have this big shader that have all those perlin, simplex, voronoi noises functions and then just make a new shader that extends the big one having just one function with stuff like:

color = perlin(x, y, z) + perlin(x*10, y*10, z*10) / voronoi(x,y,z);

Is it possible? What is the best approach? I will end up making one shader per texture, so it will be a lot of shaders and I would prefer to avoid having to copy/paste all of these functions, especially if I ever need to remake one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the common code into `.cginc` or `.glslinc` files and include them with the `#include` statement. Also see this question on [answers.unity3d.com](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7595/how-can-i-make-my-own-shader-include-file-cginc-or.html).

Another approach is to use the [`UsePass`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-UsePass.html) command.